# Rails: NameError in Devise::SessionsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, devise, admin

I  just created a new user for my admin controller in the rails console. I restart my app, enter my credentials and then I get the following message:

```
NameError in Devise::SessionsController#create

undefined local variable or method `locked_at' for #<Admin:0x4f289e8>
Rails.root: C:/rails_projects/my_blog-master

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"OKFwtFvHFqQ8fUkppNc5wSxnr8ynaIccz7MQnTNdgrw=",
 "admin"=>{"email"=>"geo.offley@gmail.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None
```

Not entirely sure why it's doing it, from what I can gather it's having issues creating a new session for my app, but I don't know how I would fix this.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Update!!

Here is my admin.rb file

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :trackable, :timeoutable, :lockable
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :lockable
end
```

And here is the migration I created:

```
class DeviseCreateAdmins < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def self.up
    create_table(:admins) do |t|
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip
      t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      t.datetime :locked_at
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :admins
  end
end
end
```

I have tried a few different things ti try and test this out and figure out what the issue is. Again any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks!!

Update:

Here is my initializer/devise.rb file

```
# Use this hook to configure devise mailer, warden hooks and so forth.
# Many of these configuration options can be set straight in your model.
Devise.setup do |config|
  # ==> Mailer Configuration
  # Configure the e-mail address which will be shown in Devise::Mailer,
  # note that it will be overwritten if you use your own mailer class with default "from" parameter.
  config.mailer_sender = "please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com"

  # Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
  # config.mailer = "Devise::Mailer"

  # ==> ORM configuration
  # Load and configure the ORM. Supports :active_record (default) and
  # :mongoid (bson_ext recommended) by default. Other ORMs may be
  # available as additional gems.
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  # ==> Configuration for any authentication mechanism
  # Configure which keys are used when authenticating a user. The default is
  # just :email. You can configure it to use [:username, :subdomain], so for
  # authenticating a user, both parameters are required. Remember that those
  # parameters are used only when authenticating and not when retrieving from
  # session. If you need permissions, you should implement that in a before filter.
  # You can also supply a hash where the value is a boolean determining whether
  # or not authentication should be aborted when the value is not present.
  # config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]

  # Configure parameters from the request object used for authentication. Each entry
  # given should be a request method and it will automatically be passed to the
  # find_for_authentication method and considered in your model lookup. For instance,
  # if you set :request_keys to [:subdomain], :subdomain will be used on authentication.
  # The same considerations mentioned for authentication_keys also apply to request_keys.
  # config.request_keys = []

  # Configure which authentication keys should be case-insensitive.
  # These keys will be downcased upon creating or modifying a user and when used
  # to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]

  # Configure which authentication keys should have whitespace stripped.
  # These keys will have whitespace before and after removed upon creating or
  # modifying a user and when used to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]

  # Tell if authentication through request.params is enabled. True by default.
  # It can be set to an array that will enable params authentication only for the
  # given strategies, for example, `config.params_authenticatable = [:database]` will
  # enable it only for database (email + password) authentication.
  # config.params_authenticatable = true

  # Tell if authentication through HTTP Auth is enabled. False by default.
  # It can be set to an array that will enable http authentication only for the
  # given strategies, for example, `config.http_authenticatable = [:token]` will
  # enable it only for token authentication. The supported strategies are:
  # :database      = Support basic authentication with authentication key + password
  # :token         = Support basic authentication with token authentication key
  # :token_options = Support token authentication with options as defined in
  #                  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Token.html
  # config.http_authenticatable = false

  # If http headers should be returned for AJAX requests. True by default.
  # config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true

  # The realm used in Http Basic Authentication. "Application" by default.
  # config.http_authentication_realm = "Application"

  # It will change confirmation, password recovery and other workflows
  # to behave the same regardless if the e-mail provided was right or wrong.
  # Does not affect registerable.
  # config.paranoid = true

  # By default Devise will store the user in session. You can skip storage for
  # :http_auth and :token_auth by adding those symbols to the array below.
  # Notice that if you are skipping storage for all authentication paths, you
  # may want to disable generating routes to Devise's sessions controller by
  # passing :skip => :sessions to `devise_for` in your config/routes.rb
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]

  # ==> Configuration for :database_authenticatable
  # For bcrypt, this is the cost for hashing the password and defaults to 10. If
  # using other encryptors, it sets how many times you want the password re-encrypted.
  #
  # Limiting the stretches to just one in testing will increase the performance of
  # your test suite dramatically. However, it is STRONGLY RECOMMENDED to not use
  # a value less than 10 in other environments.
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10

  # Setup a pepper to generate the encrypted password.
  # config.pepper = "bf3ea1b40194e484490b93836a07aa303bb7c2bf0acde18ab941011fd664414b1ab520c1e8a805579f74701a4434cbdfa456305b6e432fa4b367abe9c0bed65a"

  # ==> Configuration for :confirmable
  # A period that the user is allowed to access the website even without
  # confirming his account. For instance, if set to 2.days, the user will be
  # able to access the website for two days without confirming his account,
  # access will be blocked just in the third day. Default is 0.days, meaning
  # the user cannot access the website without confirming his account.
  # config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 2.days

  # A period that the user is allowed to confirm their account before their
  # token becomes invalid. For example, if set to 3.days, the user can confirm
  # their account within 3 days after the mail was sent, but on the fourth day
  # their account can't be confirmed with the token any more.
  # Default is nil, meaning there is no restriction on how long a user can take
  # before confirming their account.
  # config.confirm_within = 3.days

  # If true, requires any email changes to be confirmed (exactly the same way as
  # initial account confirmation) to be applied. Requires additional unconfirmed_email
  # db field (see migrations). Until confirmed new email is stored in
  # unconfirmed email column, and copied to email column on successful confirmation.
  config.reconfirmable = true

  # Defines which key will be used when confirming an account
  # config.confirmation_keys = [ :email ]

  # ==> Configuration for :rememberable
  # The time the user will be remembered without asking for credentials again.
  # config.remember_for = 2.weeks

  # If true, extends the user's remember period when remembered via cookie.
  # config.extend_remember_period = false

  # Options to be passed to the created cookie. For instance, you can set
  # :secure => true in order to force SSL only cookies.
  # config.rememberable_options = {}

  # ==> Configuration for :validatable
  # Range for password length. Default is 8..128.
  config.password_length = 8..128

  # Email regex used to validate email formats. It simply asserts that
  # one (and only one) @ exists in the given string. This is mainly
  # to give user feedback and not to assert the e-mail validity.
  # config.email_regexp = /\A[^@]+@[^@]+\z/

  # ==> Configuration for :timeoutable
  # The time you want to timeout the user session without activity. After this
  # time the user will be asked for credentials again. Default is 30 minutes.
  # config.timeout_in = 30.minutes

  # If true, expires auth token on session timeout.
  # config.expire_auth_token_on_timeout = false

  # ==> Configuration for :lockable
  # Defines which strategy will be used to lock an account.
  # :failed_attempts = Locks an account after a number of failed attempts to sign in.
  # :none            = No lock strategy. You should handle locking by yourself.
  config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts

  # Defines which key will be used when locking and unlocking an account
  config.unlock_keys = [ :email ]

  # Defines which strategy will be used to unlock an account.
  # :email = Sends an unlock link to the user email
  # :time  = Re-enables login after a certain amount of time (see :unlock_in below)
  # :both  = Enables both strategies
  # :none  = No unlock strategy. You should handle unlocking by yourself.
  config.unlock_strategy = :email

  # Number of authentication tries before locking an account if lock_strategy
  # is failed attempts.
  config.maximum_attempts = 20

  # Time interval to unlock the account if :time is enabled as unlock_strategy.
  # config.unlock_in = 1.hour

  # ==> Configuration for :recoverable
  #
  # Defines which key will be used when recovering the password for an account
  # config.reset_password_keys = [ :email ]

  # Time interval you can reset your password with a reset password key.
  # Don't put a too small interval or your users won't have the time to
  # change their passwords.
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours

  # ==> Configuration for :encryptable
  # Allow you to use another encryption algorithm besides bcrypt (default). You can use
  # :sha1, :sha512 or encryptors from others authentication tools as :clearance_sha1,
  # :authlogic_sha512 (then you should set stretches above to 20 for default behavior)
  # and :restful_authentication_sha1 (then you should set stretches to 10, and copy
  # REST_AUTH_SITE_KEY to pepper).
  #
  # Require the `devise-encryptable` gem when using anything other than bcrypt
  # config.encryptor = :sha512

  # ==> Configuration for :token_authenticatable
  # Defines name of the authentication token params key
  # config.token_authentication_key = :auth_token

  # ==> Scopes configuration
  # Turn scoped views on. Before rendering "sessions/new", it will first check for
  # "users/sessions/new". It's turned off by default because it's slower if you
  # are using only default views.
  # config.scoped_views = false

  # Configure the default scope given to Warden. By default it's the first
  # devise role declared in your routes (usually :user).
  # config.default_scope = :user

  # Set this configuration to false if you want /users/sign_out to sign out
  # only the current scope. By default, Devise signs out all scopes.
  # config.sign_out_all_scopes = true

  # ==> Navigation configuration
  # Lists the formats that should be treated as navigational. Formats like
  # :html, should redirect to the sign in page when the user does not have
  # access, but formats like :xml or :json, should return 401.
  #
  # If you have any extra navigational formats, like :iphone or :mobile, you
  # should add them to the navigational formats lists.
  #
  # The "*/*" below is required to match Internet Explorer requests.
  # config.navigational_formats = ["*/*", :html]

  # The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.
  config.sign_out_via = :get

  # ==> OmniAuth
  # Add a new OmniAuth provider. Check the wiki for more information on setting
  # up on your models and hooks.
  # config.omniauth :github, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET', :scope => 'user,public_repo'

  # ==> Warden configuration
  # If you want to use other strategies, that are not supported by Devise, or
  # change the failure app, you can configure them inside the config.warden block.
  #
  # config.warden do |manager|
  #   manager.intercept_401 = false
  #   manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :some_external_strategy
  # end

  # ==> Mountable engine configurations
  # When using Devise inside an engine, let's call it `MyEngine`, and this engine
  # is mountable, there are some extra configurations to be taken into account.
  # The following options are available, assuming the engine is mounted as:
  #
  #     mount MyEngine, at: "/my_engine"
  #
  # The router that invoked `devise_for`, in the example above, would be:
  # config.router_name = :my_engine
  #
  # When using omniauth, Devise cannot automatically set Omniauth path,
  # so you need to do it manually. For the users scope, it would be:
  # config.omniauth_path_prefix = "/my_engine/users/auth"
end
```

I have tried a few things to get it done, but I have still not been able to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have added :lockable to the model but the migration didn't create the appropriate fields. Check if you have you have uncommented the lockable fields in devise migration(:failed_attempts, :unlock_token, :locked_at)

Comment: Those are not commented out in my migration and yes they are present in my model.

Comment: I put my migration and model up, I'm still having issues.

Comment: This is so weird. In your devise initializer do you have:  config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts uncommented? Also, a strategy and  key chosen?

Comment: I uncommented config;lock_strategy. But I don't know what you mean by strategy and key chosen. I guess I need to do some more reading into devise.

Comment: # Defines which key will be used when locking and unlocking an account
config.unlock_keys = [ :email ]                                       # Defines which strategy will be used to unlock an account config.unlock_strategy = :email

Comment: I have posted my devise.rb file so if you get time you can take a look at it and maybe tell me what I'm doing wrong I'm still getting my error and I have tried all I know and searched all I can to try and fix this. Any help would be great thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message by installing the [Devise3+Rails4 Example app](https://github.com/jayshepherd/devise_example).

In the example app, users are preconfigured to be `:confirmable` and `:lockable` and if you look at the table `users` you'll see columns such as `confirmation_token` and `confirmed_at` as well as `failed_attempts` and `locked_at`, while the `admin` table doesn't have these.  The `/app/model/user.rb` has those two attributes in the call to devise:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, ... :confirmable, :lockable
```

and `/app/model/admin.rb` does not.  If you add `:confirmable` and/or `:lockable` to the Admin model then you'll see this error message.  I'm pretty sure the `NameError` is caused by either a Devise or Rails class implementing `method_missing` to look for a database table with that name.

I don't know enough about Devise to know the fix off the top of my head but it should be something similar to `rake db:migrate` so that after you add those attributes in the model, a migration is generated and then executed to add those columns to the `admin` table.

I've also already configured `/config/initializers/devise.rb` to enable locking strategies, etc.. as the other answer suggested.  In addition, locking and confirming worked for Users prior to the change to the Admin model and continue to work for Users if `:confirmable` and `:lockable` are removed from the Admin model.